# Django: cannot pass variable to included template?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates

I got a problem where I want to use template including in Django.

Here is the real example:
I got 3 files:

- **home.html** (will get the context variable passed from **Views**)
- **base.html** (the skeleton template file)
- and the **header.html** (included by base.html).

If I put the code below directly in **base.html** without including **header.html**, the **{{title}}** variable passed from home is correctly called. But if I include the **header.html** in **base.html**, the **{{title}}** variable's value cannot be called.

```
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | {{ SITE_INFO_TITLE }}</title>
```

Is there any solution to this problem? Thanks.

Comment: Works for me in the way I understood the question. Can you give minimal examples of the three templates that cause the problem?

Comment: Here is the example: the **base.html** that includes the **header.html** using {% include "header.html" %}. The **header.html** contains the code above <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %} | {{ SITE_INFO_TITLE }}</title> for dynamic title generation. The **home.html** (and other template files for blog and pages) that will pass its title value (eg. context = {
     'title': 'Welcome To My Company Homepage',
 }) via context (set in Views).

Comment: I still don't see what the problem is. Why is it `{{ SITE_INFO_TITLE }}` in the template but `'title' : 'Welcome...'` in the rendering context??

Comment: {{SITE_INFO_TITLE}} is a static variable in my Conf Settings (eg. Company XYZ) while the 'title' variable will be dynamically assigned via Views. Eg. When viewing a post with title "Hello World", the full page title will be: 'Hello World | Company XYZ'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know blocks and variable are distinct in django.
If you want to pass title as a context variable  you have to set it using a declaration in base.html such as :

```
{% include "header.html"%}
```

Which in turn contains :

```
{% block title %} {{title}} {%endblock%}
```

You can also set it in home like this.
    {% block title %} Home page {%endblock%}
But I also try to set in the template context.
Without the title block.

```
def test_view(ctx):
  xa = { "title":"Sommaire"}
  return render_to_response("test.html",xa)
```

I think you can also see the `with` template tag I think it is possible to set a context variable using this tag.

Comment: Actually putting the snippet {% block title %} {{title}} {%endblock%} above in the child template makes more sense  . In my case the previous code should relied in the home.html so the {{title}} variable will be set via context. Am I right?

Comment: @duy it depends of what you want. Actually my `base.html` templates are more complex than the leafs one, maybe the title snippet place is in header.html in your case.

Comment: Yes, you're right as I also think the same. The problem is when we pass context variable to an included template (child template) it cannot be assigned. Maybe it is a logical problem.

Answer (score 13):

Could you just pass in a variable within the `{% include %}` tag? It's documented here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#include

```
{% include "name_snippet.html" with person="Jane" greeting="Hello" %}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Inclusion Tags](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) to render an additional template from within a Django template. You can additionally pass the 'child' template context from the 'parent' template.

It's a little involved for your use case but it solves your problem. I tend to use it when I'm looping a list to render each item with a custom template. I can then reuse that template elsewhere without duplicating the markup if I need to render another item of the same type.

Comment: hum... If it does solve my problem, I doubt if the Inclusion Tags could be more dynamic so my page title is generated differently in case of a blog where the Page Title of each Post are different (post.title is passed to the {{title}} variable)? And the Inclusion Tags seems to be tied to Models (the tag need to be defined in Model's class) so If I want to use it in a non-model context (like homepage's title - that only involve a view and a template) I don't know if it could help. Btw, I'm learning the Inclusion Tags via your link. Thank you.