# Django show same content (of a model) in sidebar of every page (also in different apps)

Tags: python, django

I have two apps: blog and mysite.

In the project folder, I have a template which includes a sidebar template. This sidebar is shown on every page of the project (index pages, mysite pages, blog pages).
One part of this sidebar should show a list of the latest x blog entries (independent of the page where the user is).

**blog/models.py**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=264)
    text = RichTextField(config_name='detail_text_field', default='')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

**blog/views.py**

```
class LatestBlogEntriesListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/_latest_blog_entries_list.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.all().order_by('created_date')[-3:]
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<div class="row">
  {% include 'blog/_latest_blog_entries_list.html' %}
</div>
```

**_latest_blog_entries_list.html**

```
<h4>Latest Blog Entries</h4>

{% for post in objects %}
  <a href="{% url 'blog:post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. My sidebar only shows the h4 "Latest Blog Entries", but not the posts. How can I do this?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: ‘’’{% include “blog entries.html” with objects=objects %}’’’ or something like that (sorry on my phone) but need to pass your posts to snippet with ‘with’ keyword

Comment: Thanks, but I don't understand, from where the tempalte knows what "objects" are? ’{% include “blog/_latest_blog_entries_list.html” with objects=objects %}’ does not work...

Comment: I was basing it off your example, where you say ```{% for post in objects %}```. I'm saying if your trying to render context variables in a snippet you need to pass it to the snippet with ```with``` . See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4533537/django-cannot-pass-variable-to-included-template

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get how the model info can get past to the template. My base.html includes sidebar.html, which includes _latest_blog_entries_list.html. I thought, that _latest_blog_entries_list.html  gets the data through the "blog/views.py" file, since I say model = Post, and refer to the template name.

Comment: Try to render ‘{% for post in object_list %}’ in sidebar.html. If that works move it into your latest-blog-entries.html. 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/

Answer (score 1):

I found to use a context processor, as described in this post: https://dev.to/harveyhalwin/using-context-processor-in-django-to-create-dynamic-footer-45k4

This allows to access a context variable within all pages.

Answer (score 0):

When using ListView the default object is called object_list. Try changing your code to this:

```
{% for post in object_list %}
  <a href="{% url 'blog:post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

You can also change this variable name in the view, so that when you catch it on the template, it's a custom name.

```
class LatestBlogEntriesListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/_latest_blog_entries_list.html'
    context_object_name = "your_new_object_name"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, it does not work. With the first option (using object_list), I get the object list of the individual corresponding ListView of the page (e.g. the object_list of "mysiteListView, etc.". This is not what I want, since I always want exactly the same data (of the "Post" model) to be displayed on every page.